# Load all enums from a class file.dynamically

Tags: c#, enums

This is my class file.

```
public class GetValuesTest {
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };
enum Styles { Plaid = 0, Striped = 23, Tartan = 65, Corduroy = 78 };

public static void Main() {

    Console.WriteLine("The values of the Colors Enum are:");
    foreach(int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)))
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("The values of the Styles Enum are:");
    foreach(int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Styles)))
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

}

Instead of hard-coding enum objects like Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)) and styles  I want to load all the enums dynamically during runtime and get their values. Please help

Comment: What does "load dynamically" mean exactly?

Comment: If you are only interested in the values of one enum - that one - how is the code you have not dynamic enough?

Comment: I am interested in getting all enums and all the values for that particular .cs file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing this using reflection, and its quite possible. Though code isn't very neat and pretty. I am sure it can be improved to make production quality. Anyways, below is the class I declared with enums:

```
public class TestingEnums
    {
        public enum Color { Red, Blue, Yellow, Pink }

        public enum Styles { Plaid = 0, Striped = 23, Tartan = 65, Corduroy = 78 }

        public string TestingProperty { get; set; }

        public string TestingMethod()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I created a winforms button event to fetch Every Value of its enums. Below is the event handler code, which displays every member of enum in string.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           var t = typeof (TestingEnums);
        var nestedTypes = t.GetMembers().Where(item=>item.MemberType == MemberTypes.NestedType);
        foreach (var item in nestedTypes)
        {
                var type = Type.GetType(item.ToString());
                if (type!=null && type.IsEnum)
                {
                    string items = " ";
                    foreach (MemberInfo x in type.GetMembers())
                    {
                        if (x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                        {
                            if (!x.Name.Equals("value__"))
                            {

                                items = items + (" " + Enum.Parse(type, x.Name));

                                items = items + (" " + (int)Enum.Parse(type, x.Name));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(items);
                }

        }                    
            }
        }
```

P.S. I am sure we can do some thing better than a string compare to get rid of value__ field.

Comment: this looks good. But can I get the values of the enumeration if available?

Comment: I get the member name but need the member value also.

Comment: Yes you can. I have just changed the code to give you member name and values both. Please accept it as answer if this helps :)

Comment: Although this worked, is it possible to get the value of the enum immediately after this line of code? if (!x.Name.Equals("value__")) items = items + (" " + x.Name); because the values are in a differnt loop  and names are in a differnt loop??

Comment: HI, updated the code. Now we getting name and value together. Remember this is reflection so its going to be slow, so try not to use this to bind to some dropdowns or lists.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a templated method or function.  Like "open bracket" T "close bracket" .    Then the compiler at compile time would enumerate the enumType you passed in.

However then you now have the enum type hardcoded into outer calling code.

The point of Enum is to fix the Type at code/compile time.   Please consider your use case as you may not want enums at all but a key value pair that is more like data.

(bit more..)
So in your case you would load the color enums into an array or List.  To .NET they are color enums - to you at runtime they are a list/array of valid color choices for your application so you put them into a runtime variable of type list of types color.   The list and array types let you store and reference the way you need to at runtime for your application.   Your application is using the built in enum type range as an array but that is not really what the enum type was meant to support.

Comment: I have this requirement where I need to load these enums  in that .cs file only. I am not bothered about other enums in other .cs files.